# I want to create several moving circles in Canvas in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want make aimbooster. (http://www.aimbooster.com/)
I don't know how to make several circles that change in size at the same time.

My drawing process is...

1. Create a circle.
2. Draw a circle changing its size.
3. Reset the x- and y-coordinates when a circle is clicked.
4. Repeat this process.

The way I've tried to solve this problem is...
I tried to combine the draw function and the CircleForm function into a class and use a repeat statement.
I keep getting errors.

How do you make multiple circles?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// canvas maximum, minimum size
var max_x = 610,
    min_x = 30, 
    min_y = 30,
    max_y = 466;

// Initial Circle State
var x = 200,
    y = 200,
    r = 1,
    startAngle = 0,
    endAngle =  Math.PI*2;

var moving;

var inc = true;
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

class Ball {
        move(){
        moving = setInterval(draw, 1);
    }
        stop(){
        clearInterval(moving);
    }
        position(){
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max_x) - (min_x))+min_x);  
            y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max_y) - (min_y))+min_y);
    }
        
        first_size(){
            r = 1;
    }   
    
        moving_size(){
        var size_fast = 0.09; //0.09
        if(inc){
            r+=size_fast;   
        }else{
            r-=size_fast;
        }
    }
}

let ball = new Ball();
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

function macroBall(){
    ball.stop();
    ball.position();
    ball.first_size();
    ball.move();
}

function CircleForm(x,y,r,startAngle, endAngle){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x,y,r,startAngle, endAngle);
        context.fillStyle = "orange";
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
    }
    
    function draw(){
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        CircleForm(x,y,r,startAngle, endAngle);
        rad_check(r);
        ball.moving_size();
    }   


// Circle radius check
function rad_check(r){
    if(r>=30){
        inc = false;
    }
    if(r<=2){
        inc = true;
    }

}


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    getCursorPosition(canvas, e)}
);

function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    const xpos = event.clientX - rect.left
    const ypos = event.clientY - rect.top
    console.log("x: " + xpos + " y: " + ypos);
    judgeHit(xpos,ypos);
    
}

// circle click event
function judgeHit(xpos, ypos,moving){
    if(Math.abs(x-xpos)<=r && Math.abs(y-ypos)<=r){
        macroBall();
    }
}

ball.move();
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
}
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    background:#376481 url(bg.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#page-container{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background:url(bg_stripes.png);
}
#column{
    width: 640px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:grid;
}
#top{
    height:80px;
}

.nav{
    height:20px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.nav ul{
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:220px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav ul li{
    font-size:10pt;
    list-style:none;
    float:left
}

.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#4477BB;
}

#myCanvas{
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aim_Boost</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-container">
        
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="column">
            <img src="header.png" style="width: 640px; height: 116px;" alt="AimBooster">
            <div id="page">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Play</li>
                        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;•&nbsp;News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;•&nbsp;FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;•&nbsp;Feedback</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;•&nbsp;Donate</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="thi">
                    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640px" height="497px"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <script src="javas.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a `constructor()` method to the class to start. Read about it here [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Once you have that you can use the constructor to assign the objects properties.

Push all of the objects to any array and then iterate over them to animate. This a a very basic example showing how to create multiple circles. You can also create them without a loop.

```
let ball1 = new Ball();
let ball2 = new Ball();
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let balls = [];
var inc = true;

class Ball {
  constructor() {
    this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    this.r = 4;
    this.c = "orange";
    this.speed = 0.5;
  }
  draw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.fillStyle = this.c;
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }
  grow() {
    if (inc) {
      this.r += this.speed;
    } else {
      this.r -= this.speed;
    }
  }
  incCheck() {
    if (this.r >= 30) {
      inc = false;
    } else if (this.r < 2) {
      inc = true;
    }
  }
}

function createBalls() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    balls.push(new Ball());
  }
}
createBalls();

function drawBalls() {
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].draw();
    balls[i].grow();
    balls[i].incCheck();
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBalls()
}, 50)
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
}
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    background:#376481 url(bg.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#page-container{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background:url(bg_stripes.png);
}
#column{
    width: 640px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:grid;
}
#top{
    height:80px;
}

.nav{
    height:20px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.nav ul{
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:220px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav ul li{
    font-size:10pt;
    list-style:none;
    float:left
}

.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#4477BB;
}

#myCanvas{
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aim_Boost</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-container">
        
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="column">
            <img src="header.png" style="width: 640px; height: 116px;" alt="AimBooster">
            <div id="page">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Play</li>
                        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;•&nbsp;News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;•&nbsp;FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;•&nbsp;Feedback</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;•&nbsp;Donate</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="thi">
                    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640px" height="497px"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <script src="javas.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```